# mySQL Workbench new Connection : There is no disk in drive. Please insert disk in \Device\Harddisk2\DR2

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, connectivity

I'm trying to migrate the data at my company from Excel to mySQL so I'm very new at this. I just installed the latest mySQL package via the standard installer and when I try a new connection (I'm trying to get through the mySQLTutorial) the error pops up:

```
MySQLWorkbench.exe - No disk

There is no disk in drive. 
Please insert disk in drive \Device\Harddisk\DR2
```

My setup for the new connection is as follows:

```
Connection name: local
Connection method: Standard (TCP/IP)

Hostname: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3306
Default schema: ""
```

Anyone have any ideas? I'm completely at a loss here...

Comment: So, I assume you are working on a Windows platform?

Comment: My bad, yes I'm working with Windows 7 64bits

Answer (score 0):

Did you install that on network share? Please  try reinstall only workbench using this package https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ and use default location c:\program files ....
Maybe you didn't install MySQL Workbench Windows Prerequisites. You can find links on the same download page.

Regards,
Marcin

Comment: Marcin, 

Thanks for taking the time to answer. 

The entire MySQL installation is on my C:/ drive. 

In my installed programs, I've got Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 and Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2005/2008/2010/2012/2013/2017 in both x64 and x86. I've even tried repairing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redist but it had no effect.
When I tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redist it failed because it already detected the program on my PC (I'm guessing this has something to do with the other versions I have). Do you think I actually need to downgrade my redist?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the path of the configuration file from

```
%ProgramData%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini
```

to

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini
```

in MySQL Workbench.